# Bundle of Kendo UI is not working in IIS

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am developing an application in ASP.NET MVC 4 using Kendo UI, and the entire application works perfectly by running Visual Studio 2012, but when publishing to the IIS bundle of Kendo is not working, leaving the entire interface unconfigured.
Below is the class code BundleConfig and Layout with the call:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.514/jquery.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.all.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.514/cultures/kendo.culture.pt-BR.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.514/cultures/kendo.culture.es-ES.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/noty").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/noty/jquery.noty.js",
                    "~/Scripts/noty/layouts/top.js",
                    "~/Scripts/noty/layouts/topLeft.js",
                    "~/Scripts/noty/layouts/topCenter.js",
                    "~/Scripts/noty/layouts/topRight.js",
                    "~/Scripts/noty/themes/default.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/nicescroll").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fancy").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/fancy/jquery.fancybox.js",
                    "~/Scripts/fancy/jquery.facybox.pack.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/site").Include("~/Content/Site.css","~/Content/ResetKendo.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/pwb4").Include("~/Content/pwb4.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo").Include(
                    "~/Content/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.common.min.css",
                    "~/Content/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.blueopal.min.css",
                    "~/Content/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.dataviz.min.css",
                    "~/Content/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.dataviz.blueopal.min.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fancy").Include("~/Content/fancy/jquery.fancybox.css"));


        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
        AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(bundles.IgnoreList);
    }

    public static void AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(IgnoreList ignoreList)
    {
        if (ignoreList == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ignoreList");
        ignoreList.Ignore("*.intellisense.js");
        ignoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js");
        ignoreList.Ignore("*.debug.js", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);
    }
}
```

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/site")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/pwb4")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/noty")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/nicescroll")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sure you've gone through the Kendo steps here, but just in case: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction#using-kendo-ui-in-aspnet-mvc-4-application

Comment: If you use your browser developer tools do all the bundles show up as loaded. For example, using Chrome what shows up under Sources -> Site Name -> bundles? Also, what happens if you pull jquery out into it's own bundle (as done on the official Kendo steps linked to in my previous comment)

Comment: Could you make sure that you are not running debug mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by changing the virtual path "~/Content/kendo" to "~/Content/kendoui". In my project there is a physical path "~/Content/kendo" and the virtual path can not match the physical path.

Below is the corrected code:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendoui").Include(
                    "~/Content/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.common.min.css",
                    "~/Content/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.blueopal.min.css",
                    "~/Content/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.dataviz.min.css",
                    "~/Content/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.dataviz.blueopal.min.css"));
```

I thank the attention G_P and Win.

Comment: That's why ms guys advice use ~/bundle/... in order to prevent a possible routing conflict:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 2):

Found this [documentation](http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved) on the matter explains everything very well,

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Change version number (2016.1.112) and try this:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendostyles").Include(
                      "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.mobile.all.min.css",
                      "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.dataviz.min.css",
                      "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css"));

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendostyles")
```