# kendo basic grid and telerik accounts confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

I was using a trial version of kendo grid then after the license expired my employer bought it so i was able to download (they gave access to my account - employer's account is separate)

telerik.kendoui.professional.2016.3.1118.commercial.msi

Now the problem is this is still not working, I have done the following steps to install kendo grid

I have run this installer, and have also  manually added to my asp.net-mvc application

1. js folder under my application's Scripts/kendo folder
2. css files (styles folder) under my application's Content/kendo folder

**My code**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js")

@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css")

<script type="text/javascript">
 //shorter version of document.ready
$(function () {

    //kendo.ui.Grid

    $("#grid").kendoGrid(
     {

         sortable: true,
         dataSource: {
             pageSize: 1
         },
         pageable:true,
         resizable: true,
         columnMenu: true,
         scrollable:true
     }
  ); 
});

</script>

<div id="examplegrid">
<table id="grid">
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col />
        <col style="width:110px" />
        <col style="width:120px" />
        <col style="width:130px" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="make">Car Make</th>
            <th data-field="model">Car Model</th>
            <th data-field="year">Year</th>
            <th data-field="category">Category</th>
            <th data-field="airconditioner">Air Conditioner</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Volvo</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>2010</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>2002</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My browser does not have any errors. But i cannot see a kendo grid there.

[image: Also, when i go to telerik account to]

get support it says you are not licensed for any  products (which is confusing because i downloaded the commercial version from there)

I have also posted this to their forums (from my employer's account) but it takes them at least 3 days to respond!!

Page Source snap shot

I am also adding view source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>About - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><a href="/">your logo here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                        <ul>
    <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
</ul>

                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">

        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">



 <script src="/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

 <link href="/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

When i re-opened visual studion it gave me option to update my telerik version which i said yes and it showed me the following screen.

[image: Telerik update]

After all this grid is still the same - without kendo-grid skin :S

### UPDATE

I read this topic [Widgets Are Unavailable or Undefined](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/troubleshooting-common-issues)
So i removed a redundant jquery reference and now the grid looks like the attached image.

Note: this was a separate test appication and i intend to incorporate this grid into my main application. Now the grid looks like this[image]

Comment: did this code work with the trial version of KendoUI?

Comment: yes it did work!

Comment: does it throw any error in the console?

Comment: could you please view page source and capture a screenshot of that and post here? I guess scripts are not rendering on the page because you are using Script.Render() to render script which is used to render bundles.

Comment: Why you are writing html for table ? It will be automatically generate by kendo you  just need to provide data in json format.

Comment: I already have a populated html table (in my real application) i only need to skin it with kendo.. this is neither working in the real application nor in this simple sample program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer from [Bundle of Kendo UI is not working in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088376/bundle-of-kendo-ui-is-not-working-in-iis/17097621#17097621)

So as soon as i renamed the bundle

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo").Include(...));
```

To

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendoui").Include(...));
```

It worked great!